# golang множество структур в массиве

Tags: массивы, golang, golang-struct

Как поместить в массив структуры?

Пытаюсь обработать json данные, для каждых данных идёт отдельная структура, но функция выполняется одна и та же:

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/fatih/structs"
)

type Test01 interface{}

type test1 struct {
    User        string `json:"user"`
    Success     bool   `json:"success"`
    Continent   string `json:"continent"`
    Country     string `json:"country"`
    CountryCode string `json:"country_code"`
}

type test2 struct {
    User        string `json:"user"`
    CountryCode string `json:"country_code"`
    CountryName string `json:"country_name"`
    Status      string `json:"status"`
}

type test3 struct {
    User        string `json:"user"`
    CountryCode string `json:"country_code"`
    CountryName string `json:"country_name"`
    ZipCode     string `json:"zip_code"`
}

func test() string {

    str1 := `{
   "user" : "vasilii",
   "Success" : "true",
   "continent" : "Europe",
   "country" : "Russia",
   "countryCode" : "RU",
}`

    str2 := `{
   "user" : "vasilii",
   "country_name" : "Russia",
   "countryCode" : "RU",
   "status" : "success"
}`
    str3 := `{
   "user" : "vasilii",
   "country_name" : "Russia",
   "countryCode" : "RU",
   "zip_code" : "4564646"
}`

    allInfo := ""
    rs := []string{str1, str2, str3}

    structsArr := []Test01{test1{}, test2{}, test3{}}
    i := 1

    for _, info := range structsArr {
        jsons := rs[i]

        bytes := []byte(jsons)

        json.Unmarshal(bytes, &info)

        s := structs.New(info)
        for _, f := range s.Fields() {
            if f.IsExported() {
                allInfo += fmt.Sprintf(" %+v : %+v \n", f.Name(), f.Value())
            }

        }
        i++
    }
    return allInfo
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println(test())
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
panic: not struct

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/fatih/structs.strctVal(0x4d3160, 0xc00006a2d0, 0x70, 0x4c6140, 0xc000040210)
```

Объясните пожалуйста как создать массив из структур и в дальнейшем его обрабатывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас тут огромное количество ошибок, но конкретно с JSON связано то, что вы пихаете в срез структуры вместо указателей:

```golang
structsArr := []Test01{&test1{}, &test2{}, &test3{}}
```

Вот так это должно работать. Я крайне рекомендую вам прочитать внимательно документацию пакета `encoding/json` и не использовать отражение без должной надобности.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но это явно не единственная причина...
Можете подсказать в каких местах ещё напортачил?

Comment: У вас как минимум неверные теги (`country_code` вместо `countryCode`) и неверные типы (`bool` вместо `string` у `success`).

Comment: Структуры для примера, для генерации использовался https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/, сами строки не много отличаются.
Другие ошибки относительно кода программы, самые грубые на ваш взгляд?

Comment: Только общая рекомендация не использовать сторонние пакеты и инструменты, пока тщательно не изучите стандартную библиотеку и сам язык.